# Number of ordered triplets $(x, y, z)$ if $x, y, z \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots, n\}$ such that $x \geq y$ and $z \geq y$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm a little confused about this question as my answer is different from the book I'm solving.

> Question :- Find number of ordered triplets $(x, y, z)$ if $x, y, z$ belong to $\{1,2,3,4, \ldots, n\}$ such that $x \geq y$ and $z \geq y$.

The answer given is $\binom{n+2}{3}$. And my answer is the summation $1^2 + 2^2 + \ldots + n^2$.

Comment: Perhaps there was a typo in the problem and instead of $x\ge y$ and $z\ge y$ it was supposed to read $x\ge y\ge z$? In that case $_{n+2}C_3$ would be the correct answer. Your answer is correct for the problem as you stated it.

Comment: Yeah correct! Thank you for helping.

Comment: As an aside, $1^2+2^2+3^2+\dots+n^2 = \frac{1}{6}\cdot n(n+1)(2n+1) = \frac{1}{4}\binom{2n+2}{3}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig